# How to add view which will be top of all view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am working on miniplayer in swiftUI so a rectangle view will be universally top across the application. I have tried about `ZStack` but currently its only achieving on single view. Can you please tell how can I create above all view ?

Comment: You can do this without EnvironmentObject see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70870750/swiftui-modify-state-var-from-remote-closure

Answer (score 3):

You can put in in the `App.body` over `ContentView` and use some environment or environment object to control its visibility from any place in view hierarchy, like

```
@main
struct SwiftUIApp: App {
    @State private var showView = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
              .environment(\.showCoverView, $showView)
              .overlay(Group {
                 if showView {
                    Text("Your top view here")    // << here !!
                 }
              })
        }
    }
}

struct ShowCoverViewKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var showCoverView: Binding<Bool> {
        get { self[ShowCoverViewKey.self] }
        set { self[ShowCoverViewKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `@EnvironmentObject`

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
            
        @Published var isPresented: Bool = false
       
    }

struct ContentView: View {
      @EnvironmentObject private var miniPlayer: ContentViewModel
    
      var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    
                    if miniPlayer.isPresented == true {
                        HStack {
                            Color.blue
                            // your miniPlayer View
                        }
                        .frame(width: 200, height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("Show/hide MiniPlayer") {
                        miniPlayer.isPresented.toggle()
                    }

                }
            }
      }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(ContentViewModel())
    }
}
```

**YourApp.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ReplyToStackoverflowApp: App {
    var contentVM: ContentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(contentVM)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: code crashing with following reason 
AlertTest[62264:3906035] SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:70: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ContentViewModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ContentViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.